# Adding a join to a lookkup table in existing query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query which works great.  However, I need to obtain the actual State description for the mailing address (from Code_System_State lookup table) rather than its lookup code of  c.ContactMailingStateUlink.

```
    SELECT
   c.ClientID
  , cp.ClientULink
  , cp.ProgramULink
  , c.FirstName
  , c.LastName
  , c.ContactMailingAddress1
  , c.ContactMailingAddress2
  , c.ContactMailingCity
  , c.ContactMailingStateULink
  , c.ContactMailingZip
  , c.ContactEmail
  , c.ContactHomePhone
  , c.ContactCellularPhone
  , StartDate 
  , EndDate
  , cp.ProgramStatusULink  
from Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
where  convert(char(10),cp.StartDate,120) = '2016-02-01'
  and convert(char(10),cp.EndDate,120) = convert(CHAR(10),DateAdd(yyyy, 1, cp.StartDate)-1,120)
```

I tried to modify my query as follows, but get an error:

"The multi-part identifier "cp.clientulink" could not be bound."

```
SELECT
   c.ClientID
  , cp.ClientULink
  , cp.ProgramULink
  , c.FirstName
  , c.LastName
  , c.ContactMailingAddress1
  , c.ContactMailingAddress2
  , c.ContactMailingCity
  , c.ContactMailingStateULink
  , css.Description
  , c.ContactMailingZip
  , c.ContactEmail
  , c.ContactHomePhone
  , c.ContactCellularPhone
  , StartDate 
  , EndDate
  , cp.ProgramStatusULink  
from Client_Program cp, Code_System_State css
INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
INNER JOIN client ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.code 
where  convert(char(10),cp.StartDate,120) = '2016-02-01'
  and convert(char(10),cp.EndDate,120) = convert(CHAR(10),DateAdd(yyyy, 1, cp.StartDate)-1,120)
```

How do I correctly join these tables?  Thank you.

Comment: Show the table definitions for the 2 tables you want to join. We don't have enough info yet.

Comment: The join is not what's giving the error. The column clientulink in table Client_Program doesn't exist

Comment: AFAIK, you only can refer to one table after a FROM statement, but you use two: 'from Client_Program cp, Code_System_State css'

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking by the table definitions.  Most all of the fields are a varchar, except the date fields which are DateTime.  The fields I'm trying to join are ClientULink - a varchar(50) and ContactMailingStateUlink - a varchar(5).  Both tables are in the same database.

Comment: It's old-style syntax deprecated now.

Comment: @ksauter - Thank you.  I removed the 2nd table from the FROM clause and re-wrote my clause as follows and now it works!

from Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN client c ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
LEFT JOIN Code_System_State css ON c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css.code

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark an reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join is not what's giving the error. The column clientulink in table Client_Program doesn't exist.

It's old-style syntax deprecated now in the from-clause. This is better:

```
 from Client_Program cp
 inner join Code_System_State css
  ON cp.___KEY___ = css.__KEY___
```

Comment: Yes, I should have used the Code_System_State as the next join and not the Client table again.  Thank you all very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to join a table where the column headings don't match- this could be the problem. The Data in the columns you create the join on should match.
For example if I was joining the tables I could expect there to be a heading in CP that is called **ulink** and a column in CSS called **ContactMailingStateUlink**
so the code should read

```
From Client Programme
on c.ulink=CP.ulink 
Inner Join CSS
on c.ContactMailingStateUlink = css_code.ContactMailingStateUlink
```

Comment: I agree the headings should match, but it's the way this database was designed by the vendor.  However, they do contain identical lookup data, so the join is correct.  Thank you again.